# Split menu list in two every 7 items

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I got a dynamic menu that uses bootstrap, but one menu button has about 14 child items. Way too long for a website, so I want to split it in half.

This is the code that I'm trying to replicate:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row" role="menu">
   <li class="col-sm-6">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Life Insurance</a></li>
            <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Home Insurance</a></li>
            <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Travel Insurance</a></li>
            <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Pet Insurance</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>

   <li class="col-sm-6">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Boat Insurance</a></li>
            <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Auto Insurance</a></li>
            <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Bike Insurance</a></li>
            <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Business Insurance</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I tried:

```
$tel = 1;

foreach ( $nmenuccr as $cmenu ) {

    // If id matches and category id is 11 (services) split in half
    if ( $cmenu['id'] && $cmenu['catid'] == '11' ){

        if($tel == 1) {
            $hmenu .= '<li class="col-sm-6"><ul>';  
        }


        $hmenu.= '
                <li><a href="'.$cmenu['alias'].'.html">'.$cmenu['title'].'</a></li>
            ';

        if(($tel % 7) == 0){
            $hmenu .= '</ul></li> <li class="col-sm-6"><ul>'; 
        }
        $tel++;     


        if(($tel % 7) != 0){
            $menu .= '</li>';
        }
    //Else use the normal dropdown layout
    }else{

        if (strlen($cmenu['title']) > 25){  
           $shortstrmen = substr($cmenu['title'], 0, 25) . '...';

           $hmenu.= '
                <li><a href="'.$cmenu['alias'].'.html">'.$shortstrmen.'</a>
            ';
        }else{
        $hmenu.= '
                <li><a href="'.$cmenu['alias'].'.html">'.$cmenu['title'].'</a>
            ';
        }

    }

}
```

However this returns the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/sms16v44/

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are getting extra tags out of place due to your procedure. For example, you are ++ing in the middle of your loop. Some of your <li> are also missing ending tags

Comment: yeah.. @jjonesdesign OP forgot to close </li> tag in this line `<li><a href="'.$cmenu['alias'].'.html">'.$cmenu['title'].'</a>`

Comment: Thanks I edited the post. @jjonesdesign I only found one that missed a closing tag, which ones do you mean?

Comment: If I remove the UL tags it kind of works but it doesn't wrap the col-md-6 class around the 7 items, instead it closes immediatley. Like you see here: https://i.gyazo.com/90dae793d61e068a308a1c6ecb729457.png

Comment: Is that correct that you add the `</li>` after the ++ to `$menu` and not `$hmenu` ? And can you give an example of `$nmenuccr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keepin it a junky piece of code, you can just quick-fix it this way:

```
$tel = 0;

/* .. */

// If id matches and category id is 11 (services) split in half
if ( $cmenu['id'] && $cmenu['catid'] == '11' ){

    if(++$tel == 1) {
        $hmenu .= '<li class="col-sm-6"><ul>';  
    }


    $hmenu.= '<li><a href="'.$cmenu['alias'].'.html">'.$cmenu['title'].'</a></li>';

    if(($tel % 7) == 0){
        if ($tel == 7) {
            $hmenu .= '</ul></li><li class="col-sm-6"><ul>'; 
        } else {
            $hmenu .= '</ul></li>';
        }
    }
//Else use the normal dropdown layout
} // ..
```

Working example (updated):
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13fd6974cd66c847747f44a4be9b892aa47e4979

But you should refactor your `$nmenuccr` through a function, which will make it an array reflecting the target structure of menu to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) the view-generating part of code.

**Edit**: updated operations on `$tel`.

Comment: This is going in the right direction.. Only problem is the first list is 6 items long, the second 7 and then there is one listitem left alone at the bottom. This is my code now: https://jsfiddle.net/ouut4pdu/ The <ul> tag just outside the foreach loop needs to have class: dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row but only on the menu that is being split, not all of them. How can I do that?

Comment: Slight update to code and sandboxed example up there.

Comment: Awesome, that works, but now every menu dropdown has the class: 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row' because I had to add it to the <ul> tag outside the foreachloop, else the menu looks broken. How can I only apply this to 'catid[11]' when it's outside the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to alter your code, I came up with the following. This allows you to automatically create sub menu's out of a menu. I hope it helps out.

It creates it like the following screenshot:

[image]

and the other function/way:

[image]

```
<?php

// recreating dummy menu data
function createDummyList() {
    $nmenuccr = array();
    for($i=0;$i<24;$i++) {
        $a = array();
        $a['id']=$i;
        $a['catid']=$i;
        $a['alias']="alias $i";
        $a['title']="title $i";
        array_push($nmenuccr, $a);
    }
    return $nmenuccr;
}


/**
 * Parse a menu into smaller menu's
 * @param type $menu the main menu
 * @param type $class html class
 * @param type $max_sub_items max items before creating a new submenu
 * @param type $submenu (used for recursion)
 * @return string
 */
function createMenuList(&$menu, $class, $max_sub_items) {    

    $out = "<ul class='$class'><li>";

    // shift items
    $submenu = array();
    $i=0;
    $loop=0;
    while(count($menu) > 0) {        

        array_push($submenu, array_shift($menu));

        $i++;
        if ($i == $max_sub_items || count($menu) == 0) {
            $out .= createList($submenu, $loop);
            $out .= '<li>In between</li>';
            $i=0;
            $submenu = array();
            $loop++;            
        }
    }           

    $out .= "</li></ul>";

    return $out;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param type $list
 * @param type $submenu_label
 * @return string
 */
function createList(&$list, $loop) {

    $out = '<ul>';
    foreach($list as $l) {
        $out .= '<li><a href="'.$l['alias'].'.html">'.$l['title'].'</a></li>';    
    }
    $out .= '</ul>';
    return $out;
}


/**
 * Parse a menu into smaller menu's
 * @param type $menu the main menu
 * @param type $class html class
 * @param type $max_sub_items max items before creating a new submenu
 * @param type $submenu (used for recursion)
 * @return string
 */
function createSubMenuList(&$menu, $class, $max_sub_items, $submenu = 0) {

    // create new list
    $out = "<ul class='$class'>";

    // shift items
    for($i=0;$i<$max_sub_items;$i++) {              

       $item = array_shift($menu);

        // add item to list
        if (isset($item)) {
            $out .= '<li><a href="'.$item['alias'].'.html">'.$item['title'].'</a></li>';   
        }
    }

    // check if we're done
    if (count($menu) > 0) {           
        $submenu++;
        $out .= "<li class='submenu_$submenu'>";
        // create submenu in parent menu
        $out .= createSubMenuList($menu, $class, $max_sub_items, $submenu);
        $out .= "</li>";
    }

    $out .= "</ul>";

    return $out;

}

// call menu creation function
$list1=createDummyList();
$list2=createDummyList();
echo createSubMenuList($list1, 'hoofdmenu', 7);
echo "<hr />";
echo createMenuList($list2, 'hoofdmenu', 7);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help if you could include the output array as comment too.

However, try this. Change this:

```
    if(($tel % 7) != 0){
        $menu .= '</li>';
    }
```

to:

```
    if(($tel % 7) != 0){
        $menu .= '</ul></li>';
    }
```

Hopefully it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your check for category ID 11 didn't seem pertinent to your question, so I didn't include that logic in there. Things become a lot simpler when you leave the opening and closing parts outside the loop. Then, you're only outputting your repeated item, and checking for the one case (`$tel % 4`) where you put a divider in.

```
<?php
$nmenuccr = [ // sample data
    ["alias"=>"life-insurance", "title"=>"Life Insurance"],
    ["alias"=>"life-insurance", "title"=>"Home Insurance"],
    ["alias"=>"life-insurance", "title"=>"Travel Insurance"],
    ["alias"=>"life-insurance", "title"=>"Pet Insurance"],
    ["alias"=>"life-insurance", "title"=>"Boat Insurance"],
    ["alias"=>"life-insurance", "title"=>"Auto Insurance"],
    ["alias"=>"life-insurance", "title"=>"Bike Insurance"],
    ["alias"=>"life-insurance", "title"=>"Business Insurance"],
];

$hmenu = "<li class=\"col-sm-6\">\n\t<ul>\n";
foreach ($nmenuccr as $tel=>$cmenu) {
    if ($tel % 4 == 0 && $tel > 0) {
        $hmenu .= "\t</ul>\n</li>\n<li class=\"col-sm-6\">\n\t<ul>\n"; 
    }
    $hmenu.= "\t\t<li><a href=\"$cmenu[alias].html\">$cmenu[title]</a></li>\n";
}
$hmenu .= "\t</ul>\n</li>";
echo $hmenu;
```

Output:

```
<li class="col-sm-6">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Life Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Home Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Travel Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Pet Insurance</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="col-sm-6">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Boat Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Auto Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Bike Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a href="life-insurance.html">Business Insurance</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for any length of menu.....

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row" role="menu">
<?php
        $counter = 1;
        foreach ($nmenuccr as $cmenu ) {
            if($counter == 1){
                echo '<li class="col-sm-6"><ul>';
            }//.... end of if() .....//

            echo '<li><a href="'.$cmenu['alias'].'.html">'.$cmenu['title'].'</a></li>';
            $counter ++;
            if($counter == 5){
                echo "</ul></li>";
                $counter = 1;
            }//.... end of if() .....//
        }//.... end of foreach() .....//

?>
</ul>
```